# Need a count query in access but one column only needs unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table 'tblBaseResults' setup like this

Column 1 = Name
Column 2 = Activity

The Activity column is supposed to be unique. However there are multiple Name fields. So im not sure how to get the Activity column to unique values and keep just one value from Name. 
I would prefer to just keep the values from name that DO NOT have any '?' characters.

The current Count query i have works great. However i need only ONE of the Name fields to carry over with it

```
SELECT tblBaseResults.Activity, Count(tblBaseResults.Activity) AS CountOfActivity INTO tblCountResults
FROM tblBaseResults
GROUP BY DISTINCT tblBaseResults.Activity;
```

In Excel if i do a VLookup i get what i need, but want to do it in access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tblCountResults (Activity, Name, CountOfActivity)
SELECT Activity, min(Name), Count(tblBaseResults.Activity)
FROM tblBaseResults
WHERE instr(Name, '?') = 0
GROUP BY Activity
```

Comment: i get error 'No destination field name in INSERT INTO statement (min(Name))'

Comment: Then name the columns you want to insert into. Don't you want to insert the name too? What is the structure of the destination table?

Comment: I created a new table. 3 columns. 1 = Activity, 2 = Name, 3 = CountOfActivity. Still get that error though

Comment: I updated my query. But it should have worked before actually.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. i dont know if its possible but the Name values include english and other foreign languages. Is it possible to get english as a first priority, then foreign if english is not available? I know thats probably asking too much

Comment: Even if i could just omit any foreign characters

Comment: It can be done. But I suggest asking another question where you specify the table structure to see how to differ the languages.